# Prove that 2 distributions are significantly different?

Tags: statistics

I have some data, in the following form:

```
1   0.99404 1.39165 2.58449 0.99404 0.99404 1.59046 0.39761 1.39165 1.98807 1.78926 ...
2   0.86957 2.78261 1.21739 2.78261 2.60870 2.26087 2.08696 2.26087 1.39130 2.26087 ...
3   1.89655 2.93103 2.41379 2.58621 2.58621 1.55172 3.44828 1.20690 2.75862 1.20690 ...
4   2.14477 2.94906 3.75335 2.41287 2.94906 2.68097 3.75335 1.60858 2.68097 2.14477 ...
...
```

Where each column represents the percentage time a particular hand won (AA, AK, AQ ...) in a game of hold'em, with the rows being different numbers of players. Each row sums up to 100 (percent). I'm trying to compare this to the following distribution, which I believe to be the theoretical values for the percentage time each hand will win:

```
1   1.82953 1.39905 1.37753 1.37753 1.35601 1.31296 1.29143 1.26991 1.24839 1.24839 ...
2   2.35332 1.54739 1.51515 1.48291 1.41844 1.35397 1.32173 1.25725 1.22502 1.22502 ...
3   2.76817 1.68685 1.60035 1.51384 1.47059 1.34083 1.29758 1.21107 1.21107 1.21107 ...
4   3.04183 1.73819 1.62955 1.57523 1.52091 1.35796 1.30364 1.19500 1.14068 1.14068 ...
...
```

I think it's fairly easy to see that the data are quite different, especially when looking at a graph of the data (ugly, but provided below).

I'm trying to prove this conclusively using some sort of statistics, however. I'm using excel's chi square test (for each row separately [I'm not sure how to do it for the entire chart at once, if possible?]), however it is giving me a value of `1`, which, when compared to a standard significance level of `.05`, fails to reject the null hypothesis that the data are similar. When I multiply all of the data points by 10, I get a value to the order of `10^-5` or so, which then obviously rejects the distributions as being similar. Any further multiples just reduce the value to `0`.

My question, then, is how can I prove that the data are different without adding a multiplier, if there is a way? Alternatively, am I just being dumb, and the data are actually similar? I know that multiplying each point by some multiple won't change the distribution's overall shape, but it does change the mean/standard deviation, leaving me with a different distribution than before.

Thanks for the help.

Graphs of the complete data:

Actual:
[image: Actual data values graph]
Theoretical:
[image: Theoretical data values graph]

Comment: You will probably get a lot more interest and assistance in stats.SE rather than here.

Comment: Oh, thank you. For some reason I was unable to find that SE earlier, which is why I posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing the frequencies of an event (victory) according to 3 variables (hand type, player, and real vs expected value). You can perform  within-player analyses using the chi-square test, but the cells must contain the number of events, not the percentages. In addition, you can perform an overall analysis on the whole three-dimensional table (again with numbers instead of percentages) using loglinear analysis.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks so much! I neglected to use the actual counts ...

Answer (score 0):

There are few statistical tests for comparing distribution. One of the most popular is Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.
For graphical representation you can do the folloiwng.

1. Build quantiles with the same numbers of intervals (probs)  for both distribution.
2. plot the obtained two vectors as $(x,y)$ (scatter plot).
   If the line is far from the line $y=x$ the distirbutions are different.